# Translation of website in different languages

Tags: python, html

This is related to website we are creating at work. The script for website is written in HTML and Python. We want to translate website in different languages text by text. The idea we have is to save all the words and phrases in the excel file and by using some API it translates everything and saves in the same excel file. I had an idea of using Google API but I want to save all the translations in Excel once so we don't have to pay for using the API again and again. 
I am looking for less tedious way to:
1) Save all the words and phrases from website into the excel file 
2) Translate those saved words and phrases and be able to save in the same file.

Comment: the packages mentioned on [THIS LIST](http://www.python-excel.org/) would help

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a common problem that has been solved in a similar way to what you have in mind. I would suggest taking a look at https://www.mattlayman.com/2015/i18n.html https://www.python.org/community/sigs/current/i18n-sig/ and https://docs.python.org/2/library/gettext.html which describe using the `gettext` method to display the proper translation. This is a common problem in web development that happens out of the box in web frameworks like ruby on rails.

I believe you will still have to find the translations yourself, but if you save them in the proper files there are built in functions that can retrieve the right translation for you based on the user's location.

Comment: Great Suggestion Most of our code is written in HTML.
 <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1">
                                    <div class="form-label">Verify Email </div>
                                </div>
How will I translate the phrases like "Verify Email"? Do I need to write the translation of it in every required language in excel and figure out how to import in html file?

Comment: I am using {% Words "EMAIL_ADDRESS"%} which locates the email tag in excel file and retrieve the translation.